# Is something wrong with my layout code using RelativeLayout in xamrin android?

Tags: android, android-layout, xamarin

This layout has three controls:two toolbars and a framelayout.I want two toolbars one at the bottom of the layout and another at the top of the layout.The framelayout just lies between them.I have the code like this,but it always has the error saying "No resource found that matches the given name (at 'layout_above' with value '@id/bottomToolBar')".I'm pretty sure I have set the ID of the bottom toolBar. I am so desperate. Many thanks in advance.

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
    android:id="@+id/mainToolBar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
    android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
    app:titleTextColor="#FFFFFF"
    app:title="Musics">
</android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
<FrameLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@id/mainToolBar"
    android:layout_above="@id/bottomToolBar"
    android:id="@+id/fragmentsContainer"
    />

<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:id="@+id/bottomToolBar"
    android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
    android:background="#EFEFEF">
</android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: It looks ok to me, I have implemented this layout in my app and works fine, try to clean and rebuild. Your layout is ok.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. When your `FrameLayout` is parsed the parser tries to resolve all the IDs. So it also tries to look up `bottomToolBar`. However, at this point, `bottomToolBar` does not exist in your R.java / Resource.cs file and therefore can't be found.
This ID is created later in your second `Toolbar` in this line:

```
android:id="@+id/bottomToolBar"
```

The `+` indicates, that a new id must be created if no id exists for this reference. It will then be added to your R.java file or Resource.cs file for Xamarin.

So the fix would be: Add a `+` to your reference from `FrameLayout` to `bottomToolBar`, so that an id for `bottomToolBar` is created when you try to reference it:

```
<FrameLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@id/mainToolBar"
    android:layout_above="@+id/bottomToolBar"
    android:id="@+id/fragmentsContainer"
    />
```

Source: https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/declaring-layout#id